# Combine list<object> and list<otherobject> into single flat list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an object that has a member of a list of another object.
i.e:

```
public class ObjA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    Other members....
    public List<ObjB> ObjBs{ get; set; }
}

public class ObjB
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  Other members...
}
```

I'm currently populating ObjA object within a foreach, then within the foreach loop calling another foreach populating the list of ObjB and adding it to the ObjBs member within ObjA.

Ideally I'd like a flat list of ObjA with all associated ObjBs (by ID) appended to the list. Is this possible, I've got temp lists within my page of all ObjA's and all ObjB's, just not sure on how to join them into a dynamic single flat list?

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Are you talking about LINQ's `SelectMany()` and `Concat()` functions?

Comment: Well as you present there is a many to one relationship between ObjB and ObjA -- is this correct?  That is are there many ObjBs that are associated with a Single ObjA?  If so then transforming to a single list does not make sense.

Comment: Hi Hogan, You're right this is a one -> many from ObjA to ObjB. I'm trying to have a single list say (item[0] = objA + ObjB + ObjB + ObjB, item[1] = objA + ObjB + ObjB + ObjB, etc) where objA + ObjB have a common Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, it looks like you want:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> output = listA.Select(a => (new []{a}).Cast<object>()
                                                            .Concat(a.ObjBs) 
                                                            .ToArray());
```

or

```
var output = listA.Select(a => (new [] {new {a.Id}})
                                          .Concat(a.ObjBs.Select(b => new {b.Id}));
                             );
```

---

**Original Answer**

Here's a one-liner, although it's not in the *order* you specified (if that matters):

```
IEnumerable<object> output = listA.SelectMany(a => a.ObjBs
                                                    .Cast<object>()
                                                    .Concat(new [] {a}) );
```

or if you want to create an anonymous type that has the common property(ies):

```
var output = listA.SelectMany(a => a.ObjBs.Select(b => new {b.Id})
                                          .Concat(new [] {new {a.Id}})
                             );
```

that way you can at least access the common properties without casting or reflection.

Comment: Perfect:            IEnumerable<object[]> output = exams.Select(e => (new []{e}).Cast<object>()
                                                                        .Concat(e.answers) 
                                                                        .ToArray());

Comment: Would it be possible to now remove the answers from the first item in the list? i.e. its returning the exam object along with the answers list in the first item[0][0], then item[0][1] is the first answer object, item[0][2] second answer, which is what I want but would prefer the answers list to no longer be within item[0][0], hope this makes sense?

Comment: @user3783297 you'd have to either modify the original object (which you may not want to do) or create a new object will all data _except_ the answers.

Comment: So if I've a second exam object without answers i.e examWithoutAnswers has exactly same data as exam but no answers. how would your Linq example work with that? Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Well it'll have to be just a `List<object>`, but this should work:

```
// Flat list of ObjB
var referenced = listA.SelectMany(x => x.ObjBs);

// Concatenate listA with the flat list of ObjB
var flat = listA.Concat<object>(referenced).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them in order of first A then its' Bs, second A then it's Bs etc.

```
var flat = listA.SelectMany(a => new List<object> {a}.Concat(a.ObjBs)).ToList();
```

It has to be a `List<object>`